# Store multiple dates in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel and have a mysql table for school *classes*. Each **class** can have several **dates**, continuously added, where can occur. Easy solution will be to create a many-to-many table where there are *class* and *date*. *class_id* will be linked to *classes* table but date? It would be useless to create a new table with dates, since, a part from exactly a date (yyyy-mm-dd), there aren't details to add or a primary key.

In fact I was thinking about putting dates, imploded with commas, in a *classes* column but I've understood that it's not a good solution.

What shall I do?

Comment: A second table is the right solution.  PK would be composite of FK into class table and the date itself, i.e. `(class_id, date)`, just as you describe.  No need for a third table of dates.

Comment: One date has more classes, the problem here is with: **change date for desired class** - OP can not edit date itself but relationship between the two. I mean there is not a real problem, just pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution with commas is really **bad one**, you may use L5 helpers to modify "returned string" and then update it but its really bad practise. It is **doable**!

---

#### 1-N

> Two classes may be on same date that means more dates in the database. It all depends how many classes there are. If OP has 50k (random number to demonstrate **a lot**) classes this is going to be an issue for sure.

---

#### M-N

Since you have many-to-many relationship head to the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many) and see what options you have.

I checked for you and you are going to end up with 3 tables: `classes`, `class_date`, `dates`. Pay attention to table naming convention.

Create yourself a migrations for example see pivot table migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('class_date', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('class_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('class_id')->references('id')->on('classes')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('date_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('date_id')->references('id')->on('dates')->onDelete('cascade');
        //$table->timestamps(); //I you may turn on the timestamps created_at, updated_at
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('class_date');
}
```

Alter models according to documentation and you may use Eloquent at full power.

It all depends on how many records you are going to have - **a lot**: use M-N relation otherwise 1-N.

Comment if you need more guidelines.

Comment: Thank you! But wouldn't be better to have dates in the many-to-many table without calling another table (like @eggyal said)?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use `one-to-many` relationship. As one class can have several dates.
If You have any thoughts when many-to-many would be better - please share.

Comment: Duplicates... 2 classes may be on same date = more dates in the database. It all depends how many classes there are. If OP has 50k classes this is going to be an issue for sure.